# Combining 2 exposed filters

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

Using Drupal 6. Views 2.

After googling a bit I found this module which does exactly what I need http://drupal.org/project/views_or, combine 2 exposed filters into 1 single "search box". However, it doesn't work for Views 2.

Anyone know of any alternatives? I want to allow the user to search for terms, both in the title of the node and the taxonomy tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then I believe the solution I used for a similar task is this - http://drupal.org/node/578620#comment-2750454.

Hope it helps,
Shushu

Comment: hey that's exactly what I'm looking for! But one more thing... where does this code actually go? in the Views module? I'm not very familiar with the Views module badk-end but I do have experience writing some triggers/actions and stuff. could let me know where this code goes? Thanks.

Comment: Okay I just realised I'm supposed to use 'Computed Field' loll

Comment: Did you manage ?

Comment: Then please sign my response as an answer...

Comment: is that the tick thing? sorry I'm new to drupal lol